# Crash, disabled mouse and keyboard, screen stucks, [after install nvidia driver]

Tags: drivers, display, crash

After installing nvidia driver and rebooting, the screen only shows system program problem window and 5 mins later it suddenly turn off but power is on.

[image]

How do I fix this?

I can't even try <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f1</kbd>, both mouse and keyboard are disabled.